# Warning json_decode(): integer overflow detected

Tags: php

How can I solve this `E_NOTICE`? I'm having this problem every time I use an integer that is bigger than MAX_INT. 
I don't want to disable them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use json_decode() for large integers :

```
<?php
    $json = '{"number": 12345678901234567890}';

    $jsonArray = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

    $jsonObject = json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

    print_r($jsonArray);
?>
```

**JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING** that allows casting big integers to string instead of floats which is the default.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> options
>
> Bitmask of JSON decode options. Currently there are two supported options. The first is ***JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING*** that allows casting big
>   integers to string instead of floats which is the default. The second
>   option is JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY that has the same effect as setting
>   assoc to TRUE.